# img tag only shows outline

Tags: css, reactjs

I want an `img` on my website but for some reason, I only get a square outline of where the `img` should be.

```
import img from "../assets/img.svg";

export default function Landing() {
  return (
    <img scr={img} alt={this is a img} className={styles.img} />
  );
}
```

Styles:

```css
.img {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: 1000000;
}
```

I gave it a really big `z-index` so it would be on top but still, it doesn't work. Also when I use another image like a png, it doesn't work. This is what I get. My console doesnt give any warning or error just like my terminal in vs code

Do you guys know how to fix it??

Comment: Are you sure your `img` path is correct? Look in your developer console to see if you are getting a 404 for the image.

Comment: The question is not clear yet... may you give us the project folders and file names using the command "tree /f /a" in the cmd and edit the question with it!

Comment: console doesnt give any warning or error just like my terminal in vs code

Comment: it looks like you have a typo in your code. scr should be src.

Comment: It was indeed a typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spelling mistake of src is there in img tag

````
export default function Landing() {
  return (
  <img src={img} alt={this is a img} className={styles.img} />
   
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the React Framework. Then I would
advise to use the imported image as a Component itself.
That should work. But name it something different, "img" is also
a jsx tag. I would do the following

```
import MyImage from "../assets/img.svg";

export default function Landing() {
  return (
    <MyImage alt="this is a img" className={styles.img} />
  );
}
```

Comment: how do i do this when i use .map (i will update my quistion with the .map)

Comment: To use it with .map go for this:

   `import MyImage from "../assets/img.svg";
    
    export default function Landing() {
        imageArray.map(Item => {
            return (
                <Item alt="this is a img" className={styles.img} />
            );
        })  
    } `